# how setuid does work

Tags: linux, security

setuid is in use when a program is lack of privileges, the user set a suid bit which makes it a higher privilged user.
for example the passwd command which change your current password.
that command has a suid bit which allow to edit /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow.

In a security perspective, Do anyone can set that suid bit and get privileges?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/understand-the-setuid-and-setgid-permissions-to-improve-security/#.

Comment: Did you read the wikipage [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) ?

Answer (score 1):

The setuid bit, as you stated, gives the program with the flag escalated privileges to modify parts of the system a normal user can not.

Depending on the security model this can range from full root access to specific privileges. Generally only the root user can change the setuid bit as if anyone could set it then anyone could essentially have root powers.

It is not advisable to set the setuid bit on arbitrary programs without some sort of security audit first as this can introduce weaknesses in the overall security of the system.

Comment: If only root could be a root, why there is a setuid system call?

Comment: `setuid` is there so specific programs can be set to escalate their privileges when run by normal users who do not have access to restricted files. Otherwise, using the password example, a normal user could never change their password if `passwd` was unable to change the system password files.